# Select the next TextBox in order

Tags: c#

Could somebody help me out with trying to clean up this big list of if / else if statements please? I've found that switch statements won't work because it won't handle a TextBox as the parameter. I've seen many answers involving the Dictionary, but those won't work either in my case.

```
    private void SelectNextTextBox()
    {
        TextBox newTextBox = null;

        if (_currentTextBox == keyText1)
        {
            newTextBox = keyText2;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == keyText2)
        {
            newTextBox = keyText3;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == keyText3)
        {
            newTextBox = keyText4;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == keyText4)
        {
            newTextBox = keyText5;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == this.keyText5)
        {
            newTextBox = regText1;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == regText1)
        {
            newTextBox = regText2;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == regText2)
        {
            newTextBox = regText3;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == regText3)
        {
            newTextBox = regText4;
        }
        else if (this._currentTextBox == regText4)
        {
            newTextBox = regText5;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        newTextBox.SelectAll();
        newTextBox.Focus();
    }
```

There's 10 total text boxes and when one is full it changes to the next. This is the method that tells it which text box is next in the list.

Comment: You could use a dictionary?

Comment: Don't know what the variable types are.  It actually looks like you're comparing textbox instances to strings.  I hope that's not the case.

Comment: What is `this` in the given context?

Comment: Is this `WinForms`? Just set the `TabOrder` of the controls.

Comment: "I've seen many answers involving the Dictionary, but those won't work either in my case." If you've seen many answers that give the SAME answer, it might be the right answer. *Why* can't you use a dictionary in your case? I don't see anything in your code that would indicate that you can't.

Comment: You could create an abstract method next() and override it in each class to return the next instance

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox is full"? Can they be filled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You absolutely can use a `Dictionary` solution.  Here is what it would look like.

In some initialization code, maybe the form's constructor, write the following code:

```
// global mapping
private Dictionary<TextBox, TextBox> nextTextboxMap = new Dictionary<TextBox, TextBox>();

private void InitNextTextBoxMap()
{
    this.nextTextboxMap[keyText1] = keyText2;
    this.nextTextboxMap[keyText2] = keyText3;
    this.nextTextboxMap[keyText3] = keyText4;
    // add the other mappings here
    // where key = current textbox, and value = next textbox.
}
```

And then, your `SelectNextTextBox()` method can be simplified to this:

```
private void SelectNextTextBox()
{
    TextBox newTextBox = null;
    if (this.nextTextboxMap.TryGetValue(this._currentTextBox, out newTextBox))
    {
        newTextBox.SelectAll();
        newTextBox.Focus();

        // Maybe you also want to reset this._currentTextBox at this point?
        // this._currentTextBox = newTextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is just what I was looking for. I definitely misunderstood the Dictionary class. All of the examples I found used a string / int combo and I assumed those were the only valid types. FYI I am resetting the currentTextBox with the TextBox_Enter handler.

Comment: @chiiefs This is why you must state in your question _why_ you have those assumptions (Like 'Dictionary won't work in my case), as aquinas pointed out pretty early on.

Answer (score 4):

What about an **array**?

```
TextBox[] allTextBoxes = new TextBox[]{
    keyText1,
    keyText2,
    keyText3,
    keyText4,
    keyText5,
    regText1,
    regText2,
    regText3
};

int currentIndex = Array.IndexOf(allTextBoxes, this._currentTextBox);

if(currentIndex > 0)
{
    int nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % allTextBoxes.Length;
    TextBox nextTextBox = allTextBoxes[nextIndex];
    nextTextBox.SelectAll();
    nextTextBox.Focus();
}
```

**List:**
*A List<TextBox> would also work. just replace the `Array.IndexOf` line with `allTextBoxes.IndexOf(_currentTextBox)` and the `.Length` with `.Count`*

Answer (score 1):

From what you ask, this would be my prefered way of doing things.

// Add private fields

```
List<TextBox> boxes;
int boxesIndex;
```

// In class constructor

```
boxes = new List<TextBox>(); // Then add each text box to list from first to last.
boxesIndex = -1;
```

// SelectNext Method

```
if(boxes == null || boxes.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception("No textboxes have been set");

Textbox tb;
if(++boxesIndex >= boxes.Count)
{
    boxesIndex = 0;
}

tb = boxes[boxesIndex];
tb.SelectAll();
tb.Focus();
```

Not only will this select the next text box, but will cycle back to the start once reaches the end.